# Interruption service in assembler (int 21h) and it's behavior (w/OllyDbg)

Tags: winapi, assembly, dos, fasm, ollydbg

**Hello, fellow programmers!**
I have a stupid (for your lvl) question:
*Using "flat assembler" and debugging it using "ollydbg (v2.00.01)"*

I have a following code:

```
format PE

org    100h

start:
       mov eax, 0    ; clear entire register
       mov edx, 0    ; clear entire register
       
       mov ah,  02h  ; define control character 
       mov dl,  'A'  ; character it needs to print to "standart output" (?)
       int      21h  ; interruption service call
       
       hlt
```

So, with the code above I have 2 problems:

1. OllyDbg says "Access violation when reading [FFFFFFFF]" when it comes to the line with interruption service call.
2. I rewrote the code above using `mov ah, 05h` control character. Still got an error from 1st item.

It would be kind of you to help me solve this two requirements:

1. Understanding the difference between the "standart output" and "default printer".
2. Writing a single character to *console(?)* without using `ds` register (and any previously defined data).

**My greatest thanks to everyone, who reply!**

**Solved by...**
As it comes out, you cannot use direct call of DOS services from Win32 executable.

Comment: Are you sure this is running as a DOS program in NTVDM?  From the looks of your program (`format PE`) it appears that you assemble this into a Win32 executable.  From such an executable, it is not possible to invoke DOS services.

Comment: @fuz , ahh, I see. Thank you! I'll try to find info about Win32's services. (Think it'll help)

Comment: Don't edit an answer into your question. If you want to answer your question, post an answer instead. And since you didn't do so already, now would be a good time to take the [tour].